# Nginx redirect loop when force SSL

Tags: nginx

This has been asked before but none of the accepted answers I've found worked for me.
 
I'm using this general rule to route all http-traffic to https:

```
# Redirect http
# ==========================================================================
server {

    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    server_name www.example.com example.com;

    return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
}

# Redirect non-www / https
# ==========================================================================
server {

    # ports
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;

    # domain name
    server_name example.com;

    # ssl certificate files
    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/*****.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/*****.key;

    # Redirect all non-https requests
    return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
}


# Primary Server
# ==========================================================================
server {


    # ports
    listen 443 ssl http2 default_server;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2 default_server;

    # domain name
    server_name www.example.com;

    # ssl certificate files
    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/*****.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/*****.key;

    include basic.conf;
}
```

But it does not work. Every request on port 80 redirects to itself and gives error

> "too many redirects"

I really don't know what to do...

Nginx is running inside a docker container on a swarm-cluster.

**UPDATE**: Using the edited configuration above results in a working 301 for http://example.com but runs in a redirect loop again for http://www.example.com. Using curl i can see that the http-www-Version always redirects directly back to itself...but with added trailing slash...

This is the curl-output:

```
Ignoring the response-body
* Connection #0 to host www.example.com left intact
* Issue another request to this URL: 'http://www.example.com/'
* Found bundle for host www.example.com: 0x2cf2468 [can pipeline]
* Re-using existing connection! (#0) with host www.example.com
* Connected to www.example.com (**.***.***.***) port 80 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: www.example.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.54.0
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
< Server: nginx
< Date: Mon, 19 Nov 2018 12:22:25 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html
< Content-Length: 162
< Connection: keep-alive
< Location: http://www.example.com/
<
* Ignoring the response-body
* Connection #0 to host www.example.com left intact
* Maximum (50) redirects followed

curl: (47) Maximum (50) redirects followed
```

**UPDATE #2**: I've tried several things but it's still not working. Oddly enough if i change the first server-block to

```
server {

    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    server_name www.example.com example.com;

    # test 1
    return 302 https://www.another-example.com;

    # test 2
    return 302 https://www.example.com;
}
```

then for #test 1 it's working as expected and redirects to `HTTPS://www.another-example.com`. And using #test 2 gives me 302 `HTTP://www.example.com` ...like it's ignoring the HTTPS for this specific domain...???

Comment: Could you post your the result of curl -Lv http://yourdomain.com? I tried a similar server block configuration and it worked just fine.

Comment: Ok, i have added the curl-output to my post...domain and ip has been replaced...

Comment: I couldn't find out what was wrong but I'd try messing around with the server names a bit considering that's how Nginx prioritizes server blocks.
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-nginx-server-and-location-block-selection-algorithms

Comment: I don't think it's about the order of the server-blocks...please have a look at my Update #2...that would not be an explanation for this behaviour...